# Telling Versions.app to ignore certain svn files/folders

Tags: svn, version-control, ignore

I'm using Versions & Beanstalk for svn. My app has some log files stored within a subfolder - how can I tell Versions to skip these when committing? I know it has something to do with `svn:ignore`, but surely there's a way to do this within the GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this within Versions:

1. The easy way: While you browse your working copy, control+click on the file or folder and select “Ignore "filename.txt"”. You can find the same option under the “Action” menu. — *To do this, a file can't already be under version control, so if it is, “Delete” it first...*
2. The more versatile way: Select the folder that the files/folders you want to ignore live in, and show the inspector (“Inspector” button in toolbar), click “Edit” under the “Ignore” box. In the sheet that opens up, enter file names, or patterns (the same kind of patterns as you'd use in the Terminal, not regular expressions or anything fancy) and hit OK.

e.g. to ignore all zip files and a directory named “build”, enter this in the Ignore properties of the folder directly above them:

```
*.zip
build
```

Finally, there's also such a thing as global ignores (that are used for all of your working copies), but Versions doesn't have a UI to configure those right now, search for “global-ignores” on [this (humongous) page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html) for more about that topic.

Cheers,
Dirk

PS: Check out the [Versions google group](http://groups.google.com/group/Versions), and for support questions you can always [get in touch](http://versionsapp.com/support) with us as well (I'm one of the developers).

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you. I think my confusion was because the folder had been imported into the original svn set, so as you said I couldn't ignore it without first removing it. Versions is ace, keep up the good work!

Comment: Thanks for the nice words about the app Adam, clearly there's still room for it to become better :)

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I often hit a related issue whereby a file is in the repository and I want to tweak it for local use but not commit changes, a settings file with local DB passwords for example. Is there a way to ignore the changes to that file? Using method 1 gives the error "The item can't be ignored because it is under version control. Delete it first, then try again." and using method 2 does nothing (the file is still marked as edited and is committed by default). Is there a way to ignore edited files in Versions?